# Php no detecta mi cookie de sesión al hacer una llamada Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en PHP7 y ahora quiero borrar un registro de la base de datos y solo se puede hacer si estás logeado (utilizo una variable de sesión para ello), pero lo quiero hacer mediante AJAX.

Cuando intento hacerlo, la respuesta que recibo es el HTML de la pantalla de Login, que es como lo tengo implementado para cuando no estás logeado, pero sí lo estoy.

¿Cómo podría manejar esto? ¿Se debe hacer de otra manera?

Muchas gracias.

**EDIDATO: 23/05/2018**

Pongo el código de lo que tengo hecho:

*addproduct.php*

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
  $status = 'ERROR';
    $validator = new Validator();
    $validator->add('id:Product_Id', 'required');
    $validator->add('id:Product_Id', 'integer');

    if ($validator->validate($_POST)) {
      try {
        Closet::create([
          'user_id' => $_SESSION['user']['id'],
          'product_id' => $_POST['id'],
        ]);
        $status = 'OK';
      } catch (QueryException $e) {
        Log::logError($e->getMessage());
      }
    }

    header('Type-Content: application/json');
    echo json_encode(['status' => $status]);
}
else {
  header('Location: pantalladelogin.php');
}
```

*index.html*

```
<a onclick="addProduct(1)">
  <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</a>
```

*script.js*

```
function addProduct (id) {
  const formdata = new FormData()
  formdata.append('id', id)

  fetch("/addproduct.php", {
    method: 'post',
    body: formdata
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
    return response.text()
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  });
}
```

Lo que recibo del primer `console.log` es:

```
Response { type: "basic", url: "http://localhost/pantalladelogin.php", redirected: true, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, bodyUsed: false }
```

cosa que la url debería ser `http://localhost/addproduct.php`

y el segundo `console.log` me devuelve todo el html que tengo hecho para la pantalla de login, en vez de `{"status": "OK"}`

Espero haber sido ahora más claro.
Gracias por vuestra atención.

**EDITADO: 24/05/2018**

He estado haciendo pruebas y parece que se crea un sesión para el ajax y otro para el navegador (es decir, recargado la página). Por tanto, lo ideal sería decidirse a trabajar de una de las dos maneras para cosas que traten con laa sesión.

Es decir, para las llamadas Ajax tendré un id de sesión, la cual saco con la función `session_id()`, por ejemplo `"asd23j7i677jhads2"`, y tendré otra id de sesión cuando haga cosas recargando la página.

Por tanto, mi solución por ahora (creo que al final haré una SinglePage) es hacer lo siguiente:

*La función que hace el ajax*

```
function addProduct (id) {
  const formdata = new FormData()
  formdata.append('id', id)
  formdata.append('PHPSESSID', readCookie('PHPSESSID'))

  fetch("{{ '/addproduct' | url }}", {
    method: 'post',
    body: formdata
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
  }).then(function(data) {
    if (data.status == 'OK')
      M.toast({
        html: 'Product added to the closet.',
        classes: 'toast-success'
      })
    else
      M.toast({
        html: 'You already have this product in your closet.',
        classes: 'toast-error'
      })
  });
}
```

*En el servidor*

```
if (isset($_POST['PHPSESSID'])) {
    session_id($_POST['PHPSESSID']);
}
session_start();
```

De esta manera igualo el valor de sesión del Ajax con el del navegador, ya que creo `$_SESSION['user']` recargando la página y no por Ajax, y ya así no me da problemas.

Espero que a alguien le sirva mi experiencia.

Comment: Se mas especifico y explica mejor lo que quieres, ademas coloca el código que tienes hecho para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola @kalozoya, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Acabo de añadir el código, a ver si ahora soy más claro.
Gracias por contestar.

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido la duda, quieres comunicar desde php hasta js el dato de la sesión para controlar si estas logueado. En ese caso simplemente:

**--JS(en un archivo *.php)--**

```
var sesion = <?=json_encode($_SESSION['identificadorSesion'])?>;
```

Con esto deberías de poder comunicar la sesión de php con js y ya si quieres introducirla en un ajax o algo.

También puede ser que se te haya olvidado hacer un `session_start();` ?.

Sin un código de referencia, no tengo muy claro cuál es el fallo.

Comment: No es eso exactamente, pero creo que va por ahí mi problema. Acabo de añadir código a mi pregunta.
Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Una duda, es posible que no tengas al mismo nivel los archivos? es decir que addproduct se encuentre en un subdirectorio o algo

Comment: Si, tengo los archivos a diferentes niveles. El código que he puedo es simplificado. En realidad tengo un Front Controllers y enrutadores que manejan las direcciones, pero no es problema de que no encuentra el archivos php si es lo que piensas.  Hice un echo de la id de la sesión y son diferentes el que tiene el navegador y el echo que recibo por ajax. Será problema de que no detecta esa sesión que estoy utilizando desde el navegador?

Comment: El error está en el php, te devuleve el location del final, no detecta la variable `$_SESSION['user']` (aunque creo que eso es lo que ya sabías, dada la pregunta), supongo que el sitio web que estás haciendo tiene una página de login, es posible que no cree la variable user en sesion como debe o que el nombre no sea exactamente ese, o simplemente (no creo) que no hayas inicializado la sesión antes de asignar la variable `$_SESSION['user']`, con lo cual no se guardaría esa variable en la sesión. Podrían ser más cosas, pero esas son las que se me ocurren, espero que ayude :)

Comment: La variable se inicializa bien, ya que la página desde hago el ajax solo se puede entrar si estás logueado. Lo he solucionado pasando también el id de la cookie de sesion por POST, así se iguala y tiene encuenta la sesión activa del navegador y no crea otra para el ajax con session_id(). Es una solución chusta, pero funciona. Si alguien sabe hacerlo mejor, oigo sugerencias. Gracias igualmente.

Comment: Creo que ya se donde está el problema, si los archivos tienen las extensiones que has pasado, el index prueba a cambiarlo a .php e inicializar sesión también ahí, puede que con eso se arregle, aunque no estoy 100% seguro